# Prevent automatic simplification of trigonometric functions with complex argument

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I would like to prevent automatic simplification of some trigonometric functions involving complex numbers.

The option AutosimplifyTrigs does the trick with 1/Cos[z], but not with Cos[I z].

```
1/Cos[z]
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False];
1/Cos[z]
Cos[I z]
```

gives

```
Sec[z]
1/Cos[z]
Cosh[z]
```

Is there a way to prevent the simplification Cos[I z] -> Cosh[z] ?

Comment: It depends on your further intentions. You did not describe them and this makes it difficult to answer you. The intentions may be different. Suppose you only need to show a final result of your calculations containing `Cos[I z]`. Then use `HoldForm[Cos[I z]]` or `Cos[HoldForm[I z]]`. Another possibility is that you will make further analytical calculations, but for whatever reason want to keep `Cos[I z]` as it is. Then use `Cos[i z]` instead. On the very last stage of your calculations you may replace `i` by `I` as follows `expression/.i->I`.

Comment: Continuation: However, in this second case, I would not make tricks, but let Mathematica act in its natural way. One can always replace `Cosh[z]->Cos[HoldForm[I z]]` (and possibly alike replacements, if needed)  after the calculations have been finished.

Comment: My intentions are to show the final result, I simply don't like it to be Cosh.
The solution Cosh[z]->Cos[HoldForm[I z]] is appropriate, but I find very strange that some simplifications are controlled by "AutosimplifyTrigs" (like 1/Cos[z]) and others are not. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global'*"];

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

You can use [`$Post`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html)

```
$Post = (# /. {
      Cosh[z_] :> HoldForm[Cos[I z]],
      Sinh[z_] :> HoldForm[Sin[I z]]/I}) &;

SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False];

{1/Cos[z], Cos[I z], Sin[I z]}
```

[image]

However, [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) is undone by `$Post` for these functions unless `$Post` is cleared first

```
% // ReleaseHold
```

[image]

```
$Post =.

%% // ReleaseHold

(* {1/Cos[z], Cosh[z], I Sinh[z]} *)

SetSystemOptions[
  "SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> True];
```